# How do I fix the formatting in my spooled csv file in sql*plus

Tags: sql, csv, sqlplus, spool

I am using the following script to spool output of a sql query to a csv file. The query extracts data from a view. My sql*plus version is 12.1.0.2.0

```
set colsep ,
set headsep off
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set NULL ' '
spool myfile.csv
select * from my_view;
spool off
```

The table has few columns with null values and I am required to produce the output like below.

```
12345,,,ABC,01-JAN-2020
```

But my actual output looks like this.

```
    12345


A B C   ,01-JAN-2020
```

Why all these whitespaces are coming even between the column data? For null values, there are new lines inserted and commas are missing.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Add this: `set markup csv on` before `spool myfile.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I modified the select * statement as following to get the desired output.

```
select ColA||','||ColB||','||ColC||','||ColD||','||ColE from my_view;
```

Still out of curiosity, I'd like to know if there's any other way of achieving the same.
Also using the above query messes up the header.